# Trouble implementing Summable

Tags: ceylon

I'm trying to implement classes `DistanceCM` and `DistanceMM`, and I want these to be summable interchangeably, as long as they both inherit from `Distance`.

However, I get this error:

> "Error:(46, 76) ceylon: type parameter 'Other' of declaration
>   'Summable' has argument 'Distance' which is not assignable to upper
>   bound 'Summable' of 'Other'"

...which I can't decipher... The error message refers to this line in the code below:

```
shared actual Distance plus(Distance other)
```

This is the current code:

```
abstract class Distance() of DistanceMM | DistanceCM {
    shared formal Distance multiplyScalar(Float scalar);
}


class DistanceMM(variable Float val) extends Distance() satisfies Summable<Distance>
{
    shared Float distanceInMillimeters;
    shared Float distanceInCentimeters;

    switch (unit)
    case (millimeter) {
        distanceInMillimeters => val;
        distanceInCentimeters => val / 10;
    }
    case (centimeter) {
        distanceInMillimeters => val * 10;
        distanceInCentimeters => val;
    }


    shared actual DistanceMM multiplyScalar(Float scalar) {
        val = val * scalar;
        return this;
    }


    shared actual Distance plus(Distance other) {
            switch (other)
            case (DistanceMM) {
                return DistanceMM(val + other.distanceInMillimeters(), unit);
            }
            case (DistanceCM) {
                return DistanceMM(val + other.distanceInCentimeters(), unit);
            }
    }
}


class DistanceCM(variable Float val) extends Distance() satisfies Summable<Distance>
{
    shared Float distanceInMillimeters;
    shared Float distanceInCentimeters;

    switch (unit)
    case (millimeter) {
        distanceInMillimeters => val;
        distanceInCentimeters => val / 10;
    }
    case (centimeter) {
        distanceInMillimeters => val * 10;
        distanceInCentimeters => val;
    }

    shared actual DistanceCM multiplyScalar(Float scalar) {
        val = val * scalar;
        return this;
    }
    // implementation missing
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Summable<Other> of Other​ given Other satisfies Summable<Other>
```

Notice the constraint (the `given` clause). You're claiming that `DistanceMM` satisfies `Summable<Distance>`, but `Distance` doesn't satisfy the constraint on `Other` (`Distance` doesn't satisfy `Summable<Distance>`). Try this:

```
interface Distance of Centimeter | Millimeter satisfies Summable<Distance> {}

class Centimeter() satisfies Distance {
    shared actual Distance plus(Distance other) => nothing;
}

class Millimeter() satisfies Distance {
    shared actual Distance plus(Distance other) => nothing;
}
```